# How to highlight areas in map with php?

Tags: php, php-gd

I have a country map in .png format, I need to highlight specific states in this map dynamically using PHP. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: can you be more specific in what you need? are you talking about click on a section and then it highlights? a mouse-over effect? is this something that will be set in specific instances when the map is accessed as to which portion will be highlighted? walk us through an example of how this should work please so we can help you better.

Comment: No not onclick, I want to highlight the states in a map on the basis of the data I have. For example, I have votes data, so the states from which I have got 100+ votes should be green, the states from which votes are 200+ should be blue. The data will be changed dynamically, so should be the map.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a list of all the points defining the polygon encasing each state, then use [imagepolygon](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepolygon.php) to fill in the appropriate polygons on the map image with some color.

Realistically you probably want to find a 3rd party library/component (i.e. Flash movie, JavaScript map and library, or PHP class designed for this) rather than writing it on your own from scratch. Highlighting a map isn't exactly a new problem and solving it again from scratch is tedious.

Comment: Yes Dan, I am actually looking for that library/component to do this for me instead of writing everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about US States, I would recommend trying Google Maps, and the following links. I used them for the exact purpose you're talking about (votes by state) recently, and it worked great:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_states2.htm

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/states.xml